# Create a digital signiture for files in office

Tags: security, digital-signature

I have a domain network and I also have a server in an office that runs all the time. The Domain has several users that is defined in server. So base on these users I want to create  certificates to sign documents for inter organizational purposes.(I don't need the certificates to be registered in third party CA).

What I mean is that I want to create a set of signatures that their public keys are user's username and their private keys are user's password. How can I do that?

All my client's OS are windows 7 and My server is windows 2008.

Answer (score -1):

[Disclosure: I work for CoSign]

> > I want to create a set of signatures that their public keys are user's username and their private keys are user's password.

Standard digital signatures/certificates don't work like that. -- A certificate's public and private keys are long series of characters. The certificate can and usually does include common identifying information such as the user's name and email. You can use your internal domain name/pw as an authentication system for *accessing* the cert. That's what CoSign does.

You can have one self-signed certification for your organization and use it to easily create the employee's certs. Then the employees can use their domain names/passwords to sign with their cert.

Your employee's certs are chained to your organizational cert, not to an expensive 3rd party CA. Verification: You can publish your org's cert on your website for others to use to verify your employees' individual certs. Or CoSign can publish it. See [verify.arx.com](http://verify.arx.com)

This is exactly what CoSign customers do and it works well. CoSign acts as a Certificate Authority, automatically creating and managing the certificates for your employees.

The certificates are used to sign documents/PDFs/XML files/etc. The signing process, using the certs, is authorized by the employees **using their domain name/pw.** The CoSign server auto-synchronizes with Active Directory or LDAP systems to minimize the administrative burden of maintaining the certs.

See [www.arx.com](http://www.arx.com) or contact sales@arx.com for more. Tell them Larry sent you.